# Vuejs Фильтр данных для многоуровневого массива

Tags: vue.js

До этого я хранил данные прям в компоненте в "Data()" виде массива "Technologies" и фильтровал по типам и выводил в html. Так вышло что мне пришлось вынести в отдельный файл и еще добавить к нему данные. И теперь фильтр не работает из-за такого подхода.
Как прикрутить его к такому виду данных? структура файла "data.json" такая. Мне получаеться надо отфильтровать массив по типу и вывести.

```
[
  {
    "language": "Rus",
    "Technologies":[{
                        label: "Vue Js ",
                        price: 1.3,
                        type:"js"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "CMS WordPress",
                        price: 1.05,
                        type:"CMS"
                    }],
    "Another":[{},{}...],
  }
]
```

Структура какая была до этого и как работало.

```
export default {
        name: 'testappp',
        data() {
            return {
                Technologies: [
                        {
                            label: "Vue Js ",
                            price: 1.3,
                            type:"js"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "CMS WordPress",
                            price: 1.05,
                            type:"CMS"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Yii2",
                            price: 1.5,
                            type:"php"

                        },
                        {
                            label: "другой js-фреймворк",
                            price: 1.7,
                            type:"noname"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "React Js ",
                            price: 1.9,
                            type:"js"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "CMS Joomla",
                            price: 1.1,
                            type:"CMS"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Laravel",
                            price: 1.6,
                            type:"php"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "другой php-фреймворк",
                            price: 1.8,
                            type:"noname"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Angular",
                            price: 1.6,
                            type:"js"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "CMS OpenCart",
                            price: 1.3,
                            type:"CMS"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Symfony",
                            price: 1.6,
                            type:"php"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Другая CMS",
                            price: 1.9,
                            type:"noname"
                        }
                ]

 }        }
```

Фильтр как выглядел

```
computed: {            

            filteredItemsJS() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("js") > -1
                        })
            },
            filteredItemsNoName() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("noname") > -1
                        })
            },
            filteredItemsCMS() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("cms") > -1
                        })
            },
            filteredItemsPHP() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("php") > -1
                        })
            }
        }
```

Comment: А зачем нам знать как было ДО? Нам надо видеть как СЕЙЧАС, чтобы понять что не работает.

Comment: Сейчас никак нету. Потому что не получаться реализовать идею эту какая была простоя до этого.

Comment: А с сервера как грузишь?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов. 
Например, можно скачать файл и подставить данные в массив.
Т.е. что то вроде такого:

```
async load() {
  let data = await fetch('data.json').then(  response => response.json() );
  this.Technologies = data[0].Technologies
}
```

Это самый известный путь.
Еще есть другой вариант: если данные не планируется менять после, то можно их вынести в отдельный JS файл и подключать в коде напрямую через *impor*.

Answer (score 1):

У меня data.json лежит локально с проектом. в виде

```
[
    {
    "type":"php",
    "lang":"Ru"
     },
    {
    "type":"php",
    "lang":"En"
    }
]
```

И чтоб добраться до объекта и получить как мне надо, пришлось использовать такую штуку.

```
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MYdataJson))
```

Поправьте если не прав. Я json типа  [object Ojbect] конвектировал в строку, а потом в о object. Но этот действие мне дало возможность добраться до значений таким способом.

```
this.Type= data[0]['type']
```